# How can I use a variable that is declared inside of an for loop when I'm outside of the loop?

Tags: c, cs50

I am learning C and I need a help here. I'm just working on a little program from my course's exercise, and I need to use my variable (that is inside of an `for` loop) outside of the loop. I know its a very dumb question, but I need your help. Here's the code I wrote, in the CS50 IDE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Verifies if the card_number is between 13 and 16 digits
    long card_number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        card_number = get_long("Insert the card's number: ");
        int reach_zero = 0; 
        int digit_count = 0; 
        do
        {
            reach_zero = (card_number /= 10);
            digit_count++;
        }
        while (reach_zero != 0); 
        if (digit_count >= 13 && digit_count <= 16)
        {
            break; 
        }
    }
    // Prints the card_number 
    printf("%li\n", card_number);
}
```

I just need to `printf` the card_number.

Comment: You are already printing the variable `card_number`, which is zeroed by the loop `while (reach_zero != 0);`. What is your problem?

Comment: Instead of declaring the variable inside the loop, do it outside, where its visible in the whole `main` function. Although, I'm not sure if thats what you are asking.

Comment: `card_number /= 10` You modify it so it will always be `0` after the loop. Maybe you want `int reach_zero = card_number; do { reach_zero /= 10;...`

Comment: _The_ card number? There will be 20 of them.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly your program is supposed to do. You have a `for` loop with 20 iterations where you assign a value to `card_number`. Then you modify the value in the `do...while` loop until it is 0, followed by an additional condition to break the loop. Your loop will end either after 20 iterations or when `digit_count` matches the condition. After the loop you print the modified value of `card_number` which will always be 0.

Comment: Aside: I suggest you forget the delusion that a card number is an integer, and work with a string. Once you start working with a digit string that begins with one of more zeros (such as a phone "number") you'll see why. But besides that, it's a lot *easier* to access individual digits.

Comment: in general, read up on [variable scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope)

Comment: Save the entered value of the card number separately from the value that you modify to check the number of digits.  Consider writing (and using) a function `int num_digits(long number)` to determine the number of digits.

Comment: Thank you all. 
I will look at how to work with strings in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question then just write

```
    card_number = get_long("Insert the card's number: ");
    long reach_zero = card_number; 
    int digit_count = 0; 
    do
    {
        reach_zero /= 10;
        digit_count++;
    }
    while (reach_zero != 0);
```

Comment: The type of `reach_zero` should be `long` instead of `int` because typical `int` cannot store 13-digit numbers.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks. I did not pay attention to that the variable is declared with the specifier int.:)